# Css circle with border that is hollow inside?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make a circle hollow inside, so that there is only border visible and present?

This way I have only the visual effect. But there is some object under the invisible part of circle that has a `onClick()` method and the circle is hiding this method, so how to get rid off the filling of circle? Or maybe this is some bad approach and I should do this differently?

My current css looks like this:

```css
.inner-circle{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<span class="inner-circle"></span>
```

Comment: your sample html code?

Comment: Your CSS is missing something like `display: inline-block` to make the span accept width & height in the first place ... but other than that, unclear what you’re asking - give the body a background color, and it already shines through inside the circle, so what exactly is the problem …?

Comment: the problem is that the invisible part of circle is hiding an item underneath, and the item underneath has a click method on it that I need                edit: I mean, it doesnt hide this item visually, but it hides the click method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `poiner-events: none` to delegate clicks and hovers to covered elements.
This works for all major browsers and for IE since version 11.

```css
.inner-circle{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<span class="inner-circle"></span>
```

Comment: finally someone understood my badly explained question! pointer-events is what i was looking for!

Comment: Good call! I had forgotten about that one :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you cannot give a width and height to inline elements (which a span is by default), you need to make the span `inline-block` or `block`:

```css
.inner-circle{
  display:inline-block;   /* add this */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<span class="inner-circle"></span>
```

[More information about display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 2):

Try below this.

[this link](https://codepen.io/ArtemGordinsky/pen/GLkoC/) also helpful.

```css
.inner-circle{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-color: blue;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<span class="inner-circle"></span>
```

Comment: but i need the circle to be hollow, not transparent, background shouldn't exist, I want only border to be left

Comment: can you pls just add drawn image what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after has nothing to do with the css or visual issues. The problem you are facing is that there is an element on top of another element, and the element at the bottom does not get "clicked" because of the element on top - or something to that effect. Am I right?

I think this might illustrate what is happening:

```js
const outer = document.getElementById('Outer');
const inner = document.getElementById('Inner');

outer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  alert('Clicked outer');
}, false);

inner.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  alert('Clicked inner');
}, false);
```

```css
#Outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}

#Ontop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Outer">
  <div id="Inner">
    click me!
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Ontop">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

I don't know if your problem can be solved with css or if you have to put a new click event on the top element that calls the event on the element underneath:

```
const ontop = document.getElementById('Ontop');

ontop.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  inner.click();
}, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

For your task is better to use [canvas](https://caniuse.com/#search=canvas)

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637163/one-side-border-to-circle-in-canvas). You could adopt it to your task.

Also you could put in your code 2 different circles with borders.

```js
var ctx;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var leftValue = 250;
var topValue = 150; 

drawWheel1();

function drawWheel1() {
    if(canvas.getContext) {
     var outsideRadius = 120;
     var insideRadius = 80;
        var arc = Math.PI * 2;
  
        //Initialization
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      
        //Draw the outer arc
       ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
       ctx.fillStyle = "#029990";
       ctx.arc(leftValue, topValue, outsideRadius, 0, arc, false);     
        ctx.stroke();
       ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      
        //Draw the inner arc
        ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.arc(leftValue, topValue, insideRadius, arc, 0, true);
        ctx.stroke();
       ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="580"></canvas>
```

Comment: this is an option, but how to paint this hollow circle on canvas?

Comment: @ChrisK., I've added one more link

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18829357)

Comment: @VishvaDave, gotcha!